# Magento: How can I allow tiered price of 0

Tags: magento, import, product

I have a product csv with about 50k products in it that I am trying to import using amartinez plugin which works great for the majority of the products.

The problem is, many of them are free products with a price of 0 for all customer groups. When I try to import through the script I get an error about the tier price, and when I manually try to set a product to 0 price I also get an error: "Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field."

How can I do this? As an extra caveat this import will have to run via cron once a day (csv comes from a web service) - so manually doing anything each time is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up just making it so that the products that are free do not have tiered prices, and just have the standard price set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty fix would be to change all zero qtys to some unique number like 10221 then when you are done with your import go to *phpMyAdmin* or whichever tool you use, and run `UPDATE  catalog_product_entity_tier_price SET qty = 0 WHERE qty = 10221`

Comment: I'm sure that would work but I worry about introducing new bugs with methods like this, I would think that as this validation has been put in place then something else in the system requires this value to be >0...what do you think?

Comment: From my experience updating this table alone should be sufficient, but of course do it in a dev environment and make sure it is the case.